# Which algorithm to find out shortest path of a node to another node of X type

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, shortest-path

I have a graph that can be composed of 2 types of algorithms: **Cluster** and **Normal**.

I need a way to find out wish type of node is my normal node based on its nearest node of type cluster:

[image]

- So for example in pic above, I want to know what type is Node (A) bases on its nearest node of type cluster.
- As you can see **normal `node A`** has a **distance of 1** edge/link to node **`Cluster 1`**.
- Also, node A**`strong text`** has **distance of 2** edges/links to node **`Cluster 2`**.
- Since distance to Cluster 1 **is less** than distance to Cluster 2. **Node (a) is Type 1**.
- if distance to Cluster 2 was shorter than distance to Cluster 1 then it would be type 2.

I'm using javascript + d3 for this graph.

I searched on the internet and found that Djikastra's algorithm might be what I need but Djikastras need an initial node and a goal node.

## My problem is:

That all of my Cluster type nodes are my goals and I need to find for each normal type node which type it would be based on its nearest cluster.

Is Djikstra's the best algorithm for this? I'm not sure if in a fairly complex graph with hundreds of nodes that algorithm will perform efficiently.

This is more or less how my nodes and links look:

```
Node A = {
   name: A,
   type: normal,
   id: node_1
}

Node Cluster 1 = {
   name: Cluster 1,
   type: cluster,
   id: node_2
}

Edge or link = {
   from= node_1,
   to= node_2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best algorithm for this problem would be a breadth-first search. You can stop the search as soon as you identify a node that is of type cluster.

Comment: thanks it took me a long time to complete but it really was this the algorithm to do